# Android SyncAdapter frequency

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I'm trying to build a SyncAdapter that should be run every few seconds to quick check for specific data.
I'm using following code to run SyncAdapter

```
ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, CONTENT_AUTHORITY, 1);           
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, CONTENT_AUTHORITY, true);
```

and the sync is trigerred correclty however I noticed that it's call only once every ten minutes. 
Based on android training http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html saying:

> When a network connection is available, the Android system
>   sends out a message every few seconds to keep the device's TCP/IP
>   connection open. This message also goes to the ContentResolver of each
>   app. By calling setSyncAutomatically(), you can run the sync adapter
>   whenever the ContentResolver receives the message.

The network connection i available however it's only 3G connection, not WiFi - is this a reason on long wait?
How can I make my adapter to run every 10 seconds? 
I already tried using periodic sync

```
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, CONTENT_AUTHORITY, new Bundle(), 10);
```

but it's still running every 10 minutes.

Comment: ok, I already confirmed that sync frequency is dependent on the connection type - WiFi every few second, 3G every 10 minutes.
I believe this is desired behaviour, however when the device is used (for example for browsing internet) the interval is still 10 minutes. Can it be shortened for such situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are victim of the android `SyncManager`. Consider this scenario: you add a every 10 minutes sync for your application, but you have installed my application on your phone which as well asks the manager for a 10 minutes periodic sync and my application did the schedule requirement one second before than yours :) The sync operation of my application involves a transfer of big loads of data, hence using the whole ( or almost ) bandwidth of the available internet connection. The smart `SyncManager` will see that is not wise to start another sync process until the previous is done, and so it will wait the process to end, and only afterwards fire your sync.

Comment: ok, so I have to use other methods (maybe AlarmManager) to make sure my sync is trigerred when it is needed? I'm thinking of Service setting AlarmManager based on BroadcastReceiver with SCREEN_OFF, and SCREEN_ON intents. Does that makes any sense, and has any chance to work?

Comment: The only way that you could start the sync immediately is with the method requestSync(). You could program an alarm that triggers this method at defined times, and it should work I think. And also, accept the answer if you think it is correct.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but using AlarmManager to trigger sync is a little pointless, I could just go with sync code directly in AlarmManager.
And this will also have drawback, of running sync even when the device is not used, and I'm worried it would be to much for battery

Comment: Yes, performing this kind of sync is inefficient from my point of view, but I am not sure what your aim is exactly, but usually letting the SyncManager take care of the sync process is the best and most optimized way to do it.

Comment: right now I created a BroadcastReceiver (in Service, because without service app won't respond to SCREEN_ON and SCREEN_OFF intents), and this receiver is firering or canceling AlarmManager. Working ok, for further tests I will check battery consumption and other things. 
Thanks for your help :)